# Splitting a string and then passing it to a function

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I have the following code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    If Not TextBox1.Text = "" Then
        If TextBox1.Text.Contains("ping") Then
            Dim PingSplit = TextBox1.Text.Split(" ")
        End If

        Select Case TextBox1.Text

            Case "ping"
                MsgBox(PingSplit(2).ToString)' debug
                '  If Not Regex.Match(PingSplit(2), "\A(\d{1,2}/(1[0-99]\d)/(2[0-55]\d)).(\d{1,2}/(1[0-99]\d)/(2[0-55]\d)).(\d{1,2}/(1[0-99]\d)/(2[0-55]\d)).(\d{1,2}/(1[0-99]\d)/(2[0-55]\d))\Z").Success Then
                MsgBox("Invalid address!")
                Else
                MsgBox(GetPingMs(PingSplit(2)))
                End If
        End Select

    Else
        MsgBox("System: Please insert a command!")
    End If
End Sub
```

However I cannot work out how to get the code to split the text in textbox1 and pass the second half to the GetPingMs function, I know the function works, I just cannot work out how to pass the data. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `PingSplit(2)` is the third part not the "second half".

Comment: try PingSplit(1) instead of PingSplit(2)

Comment: What is the "second half" - Give example with data pls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `PingSplit` is declared inside `If` and is not available in `Select`.

Also I do not understand which cases your try to select in TextBox1.Text

Move declaration of your 'PingSplit' before all `if`, but still inside that function:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim PingSplit as String
If Not TextBox1.Text = "" Then
        If TextBox1.Text.Contains("ping") Then
            PingSplit = TextBox1.Text.Split(" ")
        End If

        Select Case TextBox1.Text

            Case "ping"
                MsgBox(PingSplit(1).ToString)' debug

                ' Commented if by question author.
                '  If Not Regex.Match(PingSplit(1), "\A(\d{1,2}/(1[0-99]\d)/(2[0-55]\d)).(\d{1,2}/(1[0-99]\d)/(2[0-55]\d)).(\d{1,2}/(1[0-99]\d)/(2[0-55]\d)).(\d{1,2}/(1[0-99]\d)/(2[0-55]\d))\Z").Success Then
                'MsgBox("Invalid address!")
                'Else
                'MsgBox(GetPingMs(PingSplit(1)))
                'End If
        End Select

    Else
        MsgBox("System: Please insert a command!")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I think the problem is that when I try to select the case, I don't know how to filter textbox1's text so that it accepts "ping *", I'm not sure if I'd have to use a wild card or something.